# Template for pgfplots generating temperature-time-diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

is it possible to make a template using `pgfplots` to generate plots like the following by only defining the time of the plateaus (in the example below 20 min, 25 min & 3 min) and the temperatures (here 58 °C, 63 °C, 73 °C & 78 °C). The slope of the segments between the plateaus is always 1 °C/min.

Thank you!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            width=15cm,height=10cm,
            xmin=0,ymax=100,
            xlabel=Zeit / min,
            ylabel=Temperatur / °C
            ]
%\addplot[color=red]{exp(x)};
\addplot[color=red,ultra thick] coordinates {(0,58) (5,63)};
\addplot[color=red,ultra thick] coordinates {(5,63) (25,63)};
\addplot[color=red,ultra thick] coordinates {(25,63) (35,73)};
\addplot[color=red,ultra thick] coordinates {(35,73) (60,73)};
\addplot[color=red,ultra thick] coordinates {(60,73) (65,78)};
\addplot[color=red,ultra thick] coordinates {(65,78) (68,78)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you put all the coordinates in the same `\addplot`? (avoiding the repetions)

Comment: @Rmano is that important to find a solution?

Comment: Probably not (but then I didn't understand the problem) --- it couldn't become easier that `...coordinate {(3,58) (20,58) (25, 63) ... }` ?

Comment: My target is to generate plots like this with various times a certain temperature is constant without calculating the new times. In my not very deep knowledge of pgfplots I imagine it could be possible to define a new command like this: `\customplot{starting temperature}{first temperature}[first time]{second temperature}[second time]…{ending temperature}[ending time]` (For this example `\customplot{58}{63}[20]{73}[25]{78}[3]`). This should generate a plot.

Comment: Maybe it's possible with LaTeX3 and lists. Plain commands  --- I do not know; TeX has a maximum of 10 parameters and expansion inside a `axis` environment is ...tricky. I would write an external script in python that generates the correct `coordinates {...` list. Or maybe using `lualatex` and a LUA function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does something of that sort. You only specify the plateau values and the time the plateau value lasts (and the coordinate of the first plateau).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{add temperature coordinates/.code={%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{[index]0}\of\loadedtable%
\let\myt\pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{[index]1}\of\loadedtable%
\let\myp\pgfplotsretval
\ifnum#1=0\relax
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{\xmin}%
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{\myt-(\xstart-\xmin)}%
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpx}{\xstart+\myp}%
 \edef\mytempcoords{(\myx,\myy) (\xstart,\myt) (\tmpx,\myt)}%
\else
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{\tmpx+(\myt-\oldt)}%
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpx}{\myx+\myp}%
 \edef\mytempcoords{\mytempcoords (\myx,\myt) (\tmpx,\myt)}%
\fi
\let\oldt\myt
}}
\pgfplotstableread{% this table contains the temperatures and plateau values
63 20
73 25
78 3
}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\loadedtable}% find out how many rows the table has
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\edef\xstart{5}% you need to specify the x value of the start of the first plateau
\edef\xmin{0}% plot starts at xmin
% create macro in which the coordinats are stored
\tikzset{add temperature coordinates/.list={0,...,\numrows}}
% plot
\begin{axis}[width=15cm,height=10cm,
            xmin=\xmin,ymax=100,
            xlabel=time,
            ylabel=temperature]
 \addplot[color=red,ultra thick] coordinates {\mytempcoords};           
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can also make it a macro. Then all you need to do is to say

```
\TempPlot{63 20\\
73 25\\
78 3\\
}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\tikzset{temp plot/.cd,
add temperature coordinates/.code={%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{[index]0}\of\loadedtable%
\let\myt\pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{[index]1}\of\loadedtable%
\let\myp\pgfplotsretval
\ifnum#1=0\relax
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/temp plot/xmin}}%
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{\myt-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/temp plot/xstart}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/temp plot/xmin})}%
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpx}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/temp plot/xstart}+\myp}%
 \edef\mytempcoords{(\myx,\myy) (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/temp plot/xstart},\myt) (\tmpx,\myt)}%
\else
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{\tmpx+(\myt-\oldt)}%
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpx}{\myx+\myp}%
 \edef\mytempcoords{\mytempcoords (\myx,\myt) (\tmpx,\myt)}%
\fi
\let\oldt\myt
},xmin/.initial=0,xstart/.initial=5}
\newcommand{\TempPlot}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{temp plot/.cd,#1}%
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\]{% this table contains the temperatures and plateau values
#2
}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\loadedtable}% find out how many rows the table has
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
% create macro in which the coordinats are stored
\tikzset{temp plot/add temperature coordinates/.list={0,...,\numrows}}
% plot
\begin{axis}[width=15cm,height=10cm,
            xmin=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/temp plot/xmin},ymax=100,
            xlabel=time,
            ylabel=temperature]
 \addplot[color=red,ultra thick] coordinates {\mytempcoords};           
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\TempPlot{63 20\\
73 25\\
78 3\\
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @user237299, thank you, that's quite cool already! The only problem I still have is that I need to set the starting temperature (thus the y-intercept) and the time of the first plateau should be dependent of this starting point (now the starting temperature is dependent of the time of the first plateau). Is it possible to include that in the macro?

Comment: @simande This is already part of the macro. Try e.g. `\TempPlot[xstart=10]{63 20\\
73 25\\
78 3\\
}`.

Comment: I think I expressed myself unclearly. I need to set the starting temperature, mathematically speaking the y-intercept. With xstart=10 I set the x value for the first plateau, right? Is there a way to set a "y-start"?

Comment: @simande If the slope is 1, then you cannot set `xstart` and `ystart`  separately as this would either over constrain the system or lead to a redundancy.